# Repair a burned trace on a PCB

Tags: pcb, repair, damage

I've got a PCB (from a multimeter) that apparently has 2 traces on the PCB burned away.
How they did it, I don't exactly know, but the traces are really gone completely.
The problem is however, that these traces disappeared up to a via they were connecting to...

So little graphical representation("=" = trace, "-" = disappeared trace, "o" = via) : =====-----o

Another complication: if I would solder a small wire through the via, it can't protrude at the other side, because the other side are the sliding contacts of the dial of this multimeter.

So, who's got the best option to repair these traces? Thanks!

Comment: _I_  know how the trace burned away. I once had a newly populated PCB sitting on my workbench and hadn't noticed a few leftovers of cut off pins on the table. One caused a short between two 230V~ traces. Result when I plugged it in: trace literally evaporated over a length of 5cm and board jumping a centimeter high. The copper from the trace was deposited on the sheet of paper the board was sitting on.

Comment: @steven - Yup, I've seen it as well, on a motor controller.  This one had 120V AC over a 20-mil trace.  Result: Evaporation, right through the soldermask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scrape any solder mask away from the via and solder to the via itself.  Use very thin wire, since this trace is acting as a fuse.  Or throw this meter in the trash before someone gets hurt.

There's probably something you can do with conductive glue, but I have no experience with it.

Where else does the trace go?  You can connect anywhere else on the circuit node and it should work.  (Not always.)

Comment: Well, you were right on the "throw this meter in the trash part": the tin wire was indeed acting as a fuse trying it on 230V evaporated it :), but it was worth the try...

Comment: @jpjacobs - Do you believe that it was an intentional fuse trace?  If so, you could probably glue on a fuseholder or PTC.

Comment: No I don't think so; there are real fuses present, and it was a connection from near the terminals to the function selection dial.

Comment: I like to use Kynar (wire-wrap) wire for PCB jumpers.  30 AWG, insulation is reasonably heat resistant (it won't just fall off when you touch it with a soldering iron).

Comment: @Nick - I use 30-gauge wire-wrap wire with the least heat-resistant insulation I can find for the opposite reason - Touching it with a soldering iron is much easier than stripping it.

Comment: @ree: Likewise, I often strip small pieces using an iron's help, but it's nothing like some PVC wire where it will shrink a good 1/8th of an inch when you touch it with an iron.  Wire-wrap wire usually seems to be Kynar all-round.  The difference may be due to the manufacturing process (less stress?) than the actual material properties, however.

Answer (score 3):

The burnt traces are a symptom. Something shorted out and caused them to burn. Unless you can find and fix the root cause, there is no sense in repairing the traces.

Comment: No, he said "How they did it, I don't exactly know" - They probably connected it to 230VAC in a mode that didn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you place a piece of tinned copper foil on the dial side? You could solder a wire on it, feed it through the via, and solder it to the damaged trace.